# Installing python3-paramiko on mobaXterm Personal Ed. V9.0

Tags: mobaxterm

This is on a windows 8 PC.

I used the MobApt package manger, it found V2.4.1 of paramiko and installed it without any complaints as far as I can see, but when I try to import paramiko I see this:

```
[paulb.paulb-desktop] ➤ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, May  5 2015, 17:04:32)
[GCC 4.9.2] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import paramiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'paramiko'
>>>
```

Other imports work OK:

```
>>> import math
>>>
```

It similarly fails if I use it in a script:

```
[paulb.paulb-desktop] ➤ ./ssh_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ssh_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import paramiko
ImportError: No module named 'paramiko'
```

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Edit 1:

```
I haven't rebooted my system after the installation, although I have exited and restarted mobaXterm.  I'm currently running a long duration test, so not too convenient to reboot it at present.
```

I've tried another (random) package, bugzilla which I noted caused requests to be installed and I can't import requests either, so the issue may not be related to paramiko.

Edit 2:

Rebooting the PC hasn't helped

Edit 3:
I found this https://www.betteridiot.tech/blog/pop/betterblog/2018/9/python-on-mobaxterm

Which gives me a possible but messy work-around.  The link shows how to make mobaXterm use Anaconda Python.  I already have been using Anaconda in a native fashion to give me access to extra packages such as numpy and matplotlib anyway.With the suggested changes I can now use these packages in a mobaXterm terminal rather than needing to use the Anaconda Prompt which lives in a windows cmd window.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about mobaxterm, but the first bit of searching I do suggests it might have shipped with Python2, not Python3. Python modules must be installed for each version of Python on your system. Many package managers don't handle this gracefully.

Try explicitly invoking python2 and then seeing if `import paramiko` there works.

Comment: Definitely installed the package for Python3. The package manager gives a choice of python2-paramiko and python3-paramiko, and I have selected the python3 option.